# Cómo podría enviar una factura por Bluetooth a una impresora térmica? Por Appinventor

Tags: app, bluetooth, impresora, appinventor

Nesecito enviar una comanda hecha e imprirla sin necesidad de usar otras app como intermediarios, si no que al momento de dar el respectivo comando imprima desde la app que hice en Appinventor, la verdad tengo un vago conocimiento de cómo funciona la comunicación del Bluetooth y la impresora térmica es una MHT-P5801 de 58mm

Comment: Tendrás que buscar información sobre la impresora térmica en concreto, ya que por lo que entiendo no vas a usar los drivers del S.O. para esa impresora... Tienes varias instrucciones que mandar, además del movimiento, impresión, corte automático si lo tiene, apertura de cajón monedero... De momento busca info de tu impresora, te va a ser muy necesaria

Comment: La impresora es una MHT-P5801 de 58mm, la verdad no sabría cómo implementó drivers en app inventor, estoy buscando que lenguaje manejan ese tipo de impresora a ver.